# SQL Server Download Docker Issue for Mac

Tags: terminal, password

I am trying to download SQL Server on Mac and when I type,

```
sudo docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

into the terminal, I get prompted to put in a password.
I have tried numerous passwords with 12 characters that include upper/lowercase letters and numbers. No matter how strong I make my password I keep getting this message

```
passwords:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: it's not asking you to set a password.  It's asking you to put in a correct password.  You tried to use `sudo`, `sudo` will prompt for a password.  Sudo has an excellent man page, I suggest that you read it.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` allows to run commands (`docker` in this case) with root priviledges. So for this to work, you need to

- be logged in as an admin user
- enter your own password (the one of the account you are logged into) when asked for by `sudo`